# linq: Does ToDictionary cut down the number of columns returned?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple `Linq` query:

```
var dict = (from i in Customers select i).ToDictionary(i => i.Id1, i => i.Id2);
```

Does `Linq2sql` know to cut down the select to two fields (`Id1, Id2`) although the query says `select i`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The [`Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx) class which things like LINQ to SQL rely on doesn't contain a declaration for `ToDictionary` (and there are no other classes with suitable extension methods) so it ends up using the implementation in [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) - i.e. LINQ to Objects. That uses a plain delegate rather than an expression tree, so there's really no sensible way it *could* work out what's required.

To make the query more efficient, use an anonymous type to capture everything you're going to need in the `Select` part:

```
var dict = db.Customers
             // Here i is a full Customer, logically...
             .Select(i => new { i.Id1, i.Id2 })
             // But here p is just the pair of Id1, Id2
             .ToDictionary(p => p.Id1, p => p.Id2);
```

Another alternative would be to do this as an extension method yourself - it should be possible to write an overload of `ToDictionary` taking two expression trees (and the query so far), and combine them into a new expression tree to create a key/value pair, then pass that to `Select`, then calling the normal `ToDictionary` afterwards. It's probably not worth the hassle if you're only doing this once, but if you're doing it in multiple places it could be useful.

Comment: I'm curious, wouldn't the ToDictionary be dependent on the LINQ provider's implementation? Or is ToDictionary not part of LINQ at all?

Comment: @rossisdead: It's part of LINQ to Objects - it's not part of Queryable, only Enumerable.

Answer (score 5):

No LINQToSQL cannot know to cut down the `Select` for you. You need use an anonymous type. See below.

```
var dict = (from customer in Customers select new { customer.Id1, customer.Id2 })
           .ToDictionary(d => d.Id1, d => d.Id2);
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, it doesn't. It will evaulate your query and retrieve **all** in fields on the `Customers` table.

You could rewrite it so it did:

```
var dict = (
    from i in Customers
    select new
    {
        i.Id1,
        i.Id2
    })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Id1, i => i.Id2);
```